# AJAX Request to read JSON object from node.js/express server

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express, pug

I have some server side code set up to make a request to an external website and return a JSON object that is then passed to the client side of my node.js/express application.  I then intend to perform some additional processing on the JSON on the client side.

In my index.js file I have the following code defined to render my view and make a RESTful call to the external website:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var request = require('request');

// Urls for external server REST API function calls
var url = 'https://someserver.com/appserver/portal/api/1.0/results/recent';

/* GET list of recent reports */
router.get('/testapi', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('testapi', { title: 'List Recent Reports' });
});

/* TEST: function to GET report list */
router.get('/recentreports', function(req, res){
  request({
    url: url,
    json: true
  }, function (error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
        res.send(body); // Send the response to the client
    } else {
        console.log(error);
    }
  })
});


module.exports = router;
```

Inside my jade view, I have a button set up to make a call to the /recentreports function and make a request (possibly AJAX request?) to receive the JSON object from the server.

My question is: how do I read the response from the server into my client side application so that I can process the JSON?

My jade view is as follows:

```
extends layout

head

block content
  h1= title
  p Welcome to #{title}
  script.
    // not sure what goes here
    $(function()){
      $('#getRecentReports').on('', function() {
          $.get('recentreports', function(body) {
            $('#jsonbody').html(body)
          })
        })
    }

  button(
    onclick = "getRecentReports()" 
  )
```

Edit: updated .jade code after playing around with it a bit more

Comment: Side note: on the server, couldn't you have just used `request({url: url, json: true}).pipe(res)`?

Comment: I suppose could have, so then my server side code looks like this:
    ...
    router.get('/recentreports', function(req, res){
      request({url: url, json: true}).pipe(res)
    });
    ...

If I make that change, how does that affect my method to read in the response?

Comment: It shouldn't change it, that's why I offered it as a side note. It's just simpler to type that than to explicitly provide a callback and fully buffer the request when you're just piping the response somewhere else anyway.

Comment: I see, I'll try that when I get the rest of this working.  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

My recommended suggestion:

```
script.
  $(function() {
    $('#getRecentReports').on('click', function() {
      $.get('recentreports', function(body) {
        $('#jsonbody').html(body)
      });
    });
  });

button(
  id = "getRecentReports"
)
```

Renders this:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#getRecentReports').on('click', function() {
      $.get('recentreports', function(body) {
        $('#jsonbody').html(body)
      });
    });
  });

</script>
<button id="getRecentReports"></button>
```

Or alternatively:

```
script.
  function getRecentReports() {
    $.get('recentreports', function(body) {
      $('#jsonbody').html(body)
    });
  }

button(
  onclick = "getRecentReports()"
)
```

Renders this:

```
<script>
  function getRecentReports() {
    $.get('recentreports', function(body) {
      $('#jsonbody').html(body)
    });
  }

</script>
<button onclick="getRecentReports()"></button>
```

Comment: I tried your first suggestion and got this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined.  I installed the jquery npm module with it's two dependiencies jsdom and xmlhttprequest (which I forgot to do initially).  I also added the following to my script: var $ = require('jQuery'); which then throws this error: testapi:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined.  I assume there is something wrong with the way I am referencing the jQuery module.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Read some tutorials on node in general and how to provide static requests with express, that's really basic stuff you seem to be having difficulty with. You're not really clear about where you have that `require` line. Node and client-side JavaScript don't share resources so defining a variable on one side does not allow the other side to have access to it. My recommendation if you want the easiest route is to include `script(src="url to jquery cdn")` in your jade file in the `head` so you don't have to have express serve jquery from an npm module.